# Transition dipole moment and electromagnetic radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy, dipole-moment

The transition dipole moment in 'general' space is given by

$$\left \langle \psi_{1} \middle | q\vec{r} \middle | \psi_{2}\right \rangle = q\int _\text{all space}\psi_{1}^{\dagger }\left ( \vec{r}\right )\vec{r}\psi_{2}\left ( \vec{r} \right )d\vec{r}.$$

If $\left \langle \psi_{1} \middle | q\vec{r} \middle | \psi_{2}\right \rangle > 0$, then, a transition rate from a lower state to a higher quantum state occurs.

Why is this so? Is there a better explanation someone can come up with?

---

**Edit**:

A more precise framing of my doubt might invite better responses.

During a transition between quantum states of energies $E_{1}$, $E_{2}$, the electron will be in a superposition state with a mixed wave function given by

$\psi\left ( \vec{r},t \right )=c_{1}\psi_{E_{1}}\left ( \vec{r},t \right )+c_{2}\psi_{E_{2}}\left ( \vec{r},t \right )$
with the first term on the RHS (from the left) being the probability for a particle to be in $E_{1}$ and the second term on the RHS being the probability for the particle to be in $E_{2}$.

During the transition of an electron between quantum states of different energies, the behaviour of the electron can be modelled by

\begin{align}
\left \langle x \right \rangle
& =
c_{1}^{\dagger} c_{1}\int \psi_{1}^{\dagger}x \psi_{1}d^{3}\vec{r}
+
c_{2}^{\dagger} c_{2}\int \psi_{2}^{\dagger}x \psi_{2}d^{3}\vec{r}
\\ & \quad +
c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}e^{-i\left ( E_{2}-E_{1} \right )t/ \hbar}\int \psi_{1}^{\dagger}x\psi_{1}d^{3}\vec{r}
+
c_{2}^{\dagger}c_{2}e^{-i\left ( E_{2}-E_{1} \right )t/ \hbar}\int \psi_{2}^{\dagger}x\psi_{1}d^{3}\vec{r}
\end{align}

And if $\left \langle x \right \rangle$ is non-zero, then $\left \langle x \right \rangle$ oscillates with a non-zero angular frequency which then results in a transition between quantum states of different energies.

However, recall that the transition dipole moment of an electron between quantum states of different energies $E_{1}$, $E_{2}$ is given by

$$M_{12} \propto \int \psi_{1}x\psi_{2}d^{3}\vec{r}$$

There is a disconnect between the transition dipole and the expectation value of the position of the electron. My notes claims that the transition dipole moment is the key parameter determining the transition rate for the dipole process. 
How do they all fit together?

Comment: The transition moment $\vec d = \left \langle \psi_{1} \middle | q\vec{r} \middle | \psi_{2}\right \rangle$ is a vector which is quite possibly complex-valued. What do you mean by $\vec d >0$? Does $\vec d = (1,i,0)$ satisfy it? Or should it not just read $\vec d\neq 0$?

Comment: Yea, what you write looks like amplitude of the process. What you can only say - if it is $0$, it will not happen. And - in a usual  notation it speaks about process $\psi_2 \rightarrow \psi_1$, whatever it is, lower or higher.

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend against using the notation $c^\dagger$ to denote the complex conjugate of an ordinary complex number $c\in \mathbb C$, because it implies that the symbol is an operator and you're taking the hermitian conjugate. Use $c^*$ instead.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you for the heads up/